# How to order a list of tuples by the integer value of a certain index of each, in Python?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, tuples, list-comprehension

Given a list of tuples e.g.

```
[('a','b','4'),('c','d','9'),('e','f','2')]
```

The third element of each tuple will always be the string value of an integer.

I want to write each tuple as a row of a csv using `csv.writerow()`.
Before I do, I want to reorder the tuples (ideally by overwriting the existing list or creating a new one) such that they get written in **descending order** of the integer value of that third element of each e.g.

```
c,d,9
a,b,4
e,f,2
```

I'm trying to imagine some sort of multiple if/else combo in a list comprehension, but surely there's go to be a simpler way?

Comment: (if the csv were to contain just a single list of tuples, then obviously I coudl just re-order in the csv itself e.g. in Excel. But the CSV will contain many such lists of tuples, one after the other.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `sorted` function (or the `list` method `sort`) takes optional arguments `reverse` to allow you to sort in decreasing order, and `key` to allow you to specify what to sort by.

```
l = [('a','b','4'),('c','d','9'),('e','f','2')]
l.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[2]), reverse=True)
```

gives you the list in the order you want.

Comment: `key=lambda x: -int(x[2])` will do it without needing `reverse=True`.

Comment: @kindall I guess thats just a personal preference cause it seems clearer to me with `reverse`

Answer (score 3):

In my answer I use `sys.stdout` as an example but you may use a file instead

```
>>> import sys, csv
>>> items = [('a','b','4'),('c','d','9'),('e','f','2')]
>>> w = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
>>> w.writerows(sorted(items, key=lambda x: int(x[2]), reverse=True))
c,d,9
a,b,4
e,f,2
```

Comment: This is one of the main reasons I don't get why people like `itemgetter` so much -- your sort is lexicographic, not by integer value.

Comment: @DSM my mistake, I didn't notice it was a string. fixed now

Answer (score 0):

This works in both Python 2 and Python 3:

```
x = [('a','b','4'),('c','d','9'),('e','f','2')]
x.sort(key=lambda int(x:x[2]), reverse=True)
```

`key` is a function applied to each item in the list and returns the key to be used as the basis for sorting.

Comment: Comparison sort is removed in Python 3 and you haven't specified `cmp=`

Comment: @jamylak: Good point. Have edited my example to use the technique that works for both Python 2 and Python 3. The 'cmp' function is a general comparison function that returns -1, 0, 1 to show less than, equal, or greater than for any two values.

Comment: Practically, yes, but actually `"help(cmp)   Return negative if x<y, zero if x==y, positive if x>y."` So it's negative and positive, not always `-1` and `1`

Answer (score 0):

Another one using `itemgetter` slightly faster than `lambda x: x[2]` for small lists and considerably faster for larger lists.

```
from operator import itemgetter
l = [('a','b','4'),('c','d','9'),('e','f','2')]
l.sort(key=itemgetter(2), revese=True)
```

[Python sorting mini Howto](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting) has got a lot many useful tricks worth reading.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different, albeit less efficient solution:

```
def sort_tuple_list(l):
    sorted_ints = sorted([int(i[2]) for i in l], reverse=True)
    sorted_tuple_list = []
    for i in sorted_ints:
        for tup in l:
            if int(tup[2]) == i:
                sorted_tuple_list.append(tup)
    return sorted_tuple_list
```

Returns a list sorted according to the original question's specifications.
You can then simply write each row of this returned list to your csv file.